# Android async image download placeholder size and color

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have the following requirement / scenario:

I [HTTP: POST] my Server for feedItems. Each of said items has (among others) the following properties:

- Image URL
- ImageSize (Width, Height)
- RGB Average

What I need to do now is:

- Load the image into an ImageView async.
- While the image is loaded, display a placeholder which is exactly the same size as the final image and has the RGB average color
- Optionally: Cross-fade between the placeholder and the final image once it is downloaded

(Kind of like what Pinterest does in their App)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I thought about using Volley or Picasso for this. Any tips on which of the both may be better here?
I really don't know what to do about the placeholder. - How can I make sure it has the same size as the final loaded image?

Note: The feedItems are displayed in a 'staggered Grid' (using the new RecyclerView), so the placeholders height should be something like 'columnWidth * imageRatio').
That's also why the layout really has to know about how 'tall' each item will be before the image is loaded, to avoid ugly jumps.

I come from iOS development and already created this UI in iOS using UICollectionView. However, in iOS you can really compute the placeholder size right on the last pixel (columnWidth * imageRatio) - I'm not THAT experienced with Android, so I really don't know how to achieve this.

Any hints, samples, etc. are very welcome!

Thank you :)

Comment: Same problem here! How do you solve yours?

Answer (score -2):

try universal image loader, I use it in all my apps

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.